# 'index.swf' embedded in 'index.html' showing same website twice in one page. HTML Title tag/attribute also showing the value 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I have an issue with my current website. Upon hosting this Online, the .SWF shows at the top of the page, roughly covering 1/4 and also again at the bottom, covering 3/4. If I zoom in and out, the bottom half of the page slightly covers the top, but the top is still showing. It is asif the .SWF has been embedded twice.. here is my code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="author" content="Kush Kouture" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Kush Kouture" />
<meta name="description" content="Kush Kouture" />

<title>Kush Kouture</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfaddress.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
flashvars.url_config = "xml/configuration_site.xml";
flashvars.initServices = true;
var params = {};
params.allowfullscreen = true;
params.allowScriptAccess = "always";
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = 'flashObject';
attributes.bgcolor = '#000000';

swfobject.embedSWF("flash/index.swf", "Alternative", "100%", "100%", "11.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>

<style type="text/css">
/* hide from ie on mac \*/
html {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#flashcontent {
height: 100%;
}
/* end hide */

body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
p {

font-size: 10px;
font-family: Verdana;
line-height:17px;
color:#ffffff;

} 
.style1 {
font-size: 11px;
font-family: Verdana;
color:#ffffff;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="flashContent>
<object id="flashObject" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"           codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=11,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="movie" value="flash/index.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="width" value="100%" />
<param name="height" value="100%" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/index.swf" align=""      scale="noscale" wmode="transparent" width="100%" height="100%">
</object>
</object>
</div>

<div id="Alternative"> 
<p style="color:#999999">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kush Kouture | You require the latest version of Adobe Flash Player in order to view this site. Please use the button below to download the latest version.</p>
<p><a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/"><img src="flash.jpg" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

I have also noticed that the Page Title is showing correct, but with the value 'underfined' next to it..

eg. should be 'Home Page', showing 'Homepageundefined'

I really appreciate any help that can be given in regards to the above issues.

Comment: I am very new to Javascript and CSS, so I would appreciate any advice on what I have done so far. I understand that some parts may not be required or may be missing.. thanks in advance!

Comment: can you make a JsFiddle out of this so that I can see the rendered output

Comment: Hi Kishore. Apologies for this but the current internet connection I am using has the 'JsFiddle' website blocked by policy. I will be able to do this after 6PM.. but managed to obtain upload a screenshot of these issues..

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/screenshotnpe.jpg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes perfect sense, since you've embedded the .swf with both an `<object>` tag and with `SWFObject`. Simply just use one and you'll see just one instance of the .swf.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it. Removing the <object> displays the website perfectly!. I do still have the remaining issue of the Title tag/attribute. Instead of showing 'Kush Kouture' on the tab, it shows as 'Kush Koutureundefined'.. I don't suppose you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be an issue with the XML 'configuration_site.xml' (not all code displayed);

<BACK_BUTTON_LABEL><![CDATA[<< Back ]]></BACK_BUTTON_LABEL>
<BOX_BCG_COLOR>0x022639,80</BOX_BCG_COLOR>
<BOX_VISIBLE>true</BOX_VISIBLE>
<COLOR_BUTTON_FULLSCREEN>0xffffff</COLOR_BUTTON_FULLSCREEN>
<COMPANY_NAME>Kush Kouture</COMPANY_NAME>
<SWF_ADRESS_ATTRIB>flash/index.swf</SWF_ADRESS_ATTRIB>
<SWF_TITLE_ATTRIB>Kush Kouture</SWF_TITLE_ATTRIB>
<NEW_STAGE_WIDTH>100%</NEW_STAGE_WIDTH>
<NEW_STAGE_HEIGHT>100%</NEW_STAGE_HEIGHT>

Comment: I think it's a javascript issue (or maybe php if you're using that), 'undefined' seems an instance/variable that the browser can't parse. But I'm not sure.

Comment: The majority of the site is HTML/JavaScript & CSS, I use PHP for the Contact Form (I have not used much PHP so i wont even go there, i'm without a Contact Form for the time being!). I'm currently re-reading over everything to make sure I haven't missed out any values.. would anymore code be helppful?.

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you have any javascript that meddles with the title? Or maybe a var or property you called `title`? If you're not sure you could try to leave out scripts and then see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. removing the '/' from <meta name="author" content="Kush Kouture" /> to show... <meta name="author" content="Kush Kouture"> seemed to resolve this. Not sure if this needs to be done for the 'Keywords' & 'Description', but all resolved for now!

Comment: Ok great! If the problem is fully solved, would you be so kind to accept an answer?

Comment: Hi popeje, this still seems to be an issue at the moment, removeing the '/' has not resolved this (only when I open the Web site locally to my PC) upon checking this Online, I still get the title being diaplayed as 'Kush Koutureundefined'.. anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: In fact, I will post a new Question! (save having two in one and also to give you your 'acceptance') you have been a big help! hopefully get this 'title' issue resolved!

Comment: Title issue is now resolved.. but the .SWF is still not loading on ANY browser, my website is www.KushKouture.com and the code has been pasted here -- http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32039/having-an-issue-with-my-web-site-loading-this-is-a-swf-file-embedded-into-the

Answer (score 1):

One issue may be that you have not closed the quote properly

```
<div id="flashContent>
```

should be

```
<div id="flashContent">
```

I dont see menu code here can u post that aswell?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me, I have now amended this in my code!